# How to get/fetch certain columns from dynamoDB using python in Lambda?

Tags: python, pandas, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

1. I have a table called 'DATA' in dynamodb where I have 20 to 25 columns. But I need to pull only 3 columns from dynamodb.
2. Required columns are status, ticket_id and country

```
table_name = 'DATA'
# dynamodb client 
dynamodb_client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
```

Required columns are status, ticket_id
I'm able to achieve using scan as provided below. But I want to do the same using query method.

```
response = table.scan(AttributesToGet=['ticket_id','ticket_status'])
```

I tried the below code with query method. But I'm getting error.

```
response = table.query(ProjectionExpression=['ticket_id','ticket_status']),keyConditionExpression('opco_type').eq('cwc') or keyConditionExpression('opco_type').eq('cwp'))
```

Is there any way of getting only required columns from dynamo?

Comment: You need to use a projection expression https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ProjectionExpressions.html

Comment: Yes, I read about it..But got stucked, because there we need to put key value pairs. how can I use it inorder to get all values from specific columns. Please see my updated question. @luk2302

Answer (score 2):

As already commented, you need to use ProjectExpression:

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name=region)
table = dynamodb.Table(table_name)
item = table.get_item(Key={'Title': 'Scarface', 'Year': 1983}, ProjectionExpression='status, ticket_id, country')
```

Some things to note:

- It is better to use resource instead of client. This will avoid special dynamodb json syntax.
- You need to set the full (composite) key to get_item
- Selected columns should be in a comma-separated string
- It is a good idea to always use expression attribute names:

```
    item = table.get_item(Key={'Title': 'Scarface', 'Year': 1983}, 
                          ProjectionExpression='#status, ticket_id, country',
                          ExpressionAttributeNames={'#status': 'status'})
```

Comment: #response = table.scan(AttributesToGet=['ticket_id','ticket_status'])
 I should achieve the same using projectionexpression. Any help @kgiannakakis

Comment: @Mahilan: Make sure that you understand the difference between scan and query.

Comment: Please see my updated question. I should fetch only columns with all the values. The above code is working but Is there any way to acheive the same using projectionexpression.

Comment: You mean get all items that have both ticket_id and ticket_status set? I don't think this is possible without creating a GSI.

Comment: yes, correct. Can you pls help me on this

Comment: I would create a GSI with status as the partition key. Then you need one query per different status. Post a new question that better describe what you are trying to achieve to get more help.